# Why does changing the bibliography style to "agsm" randomly bold the journal volume numbers?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, natbib, harvard-style

I'm using the `natbib` package for the bibliography, and initially had the `plainnat` style but have since been told that I've got to use Harvard referencing only. So I tried changing the bibliography styles to ones I've found on online reference sheets - e.g. `agsm.bst`, but the only ones I find that work and put the bibliography references in the order they need to be ('Author;Year;Title;Journal;Volume;Pages') will bold the volume number like this:

> JR Krebs. 1980. Optimal foraging, predation risk and territory defence. *Ardea*, **68**:83-90

It looks very odd and I would like to remove this but I don't know how - do I need to change the code, or is there a style package that I should be using?

Here's the code I have set up:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single,breaklines=true}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\sloppy

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}


\title{PAPER TITLE}
\date{}

\begin{document}
TEXT HERE
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
```

and the bibliography entries are being entered like this:

```
@article{krebs1980optimal,
  title={Optimal foraging, predation risk and territory defence},
  author={Krebs, JR},
  journal={Ardea},
  volume={68},
  pages={83--90},
  year={1980},
  publisher={BioOne}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't use `natbib`, but I can say it will be easier with `biblatex` (which has a natbib compatibility mode).

Comment: it's not random, deciding fonts for things like issue numbers is exactly what bibtex styles do so it is expected to change if you change styles. That is the intended style of the bibliography style you are using. You could make a copy under a different name and just look for places that it inserts `\textbf` but if it is for submission it is usually best not to change specified styles

Comment: if I were to switch to biblatex, which bits of code would I need to alter? I am hesitant to remove things because I don't really know what I'm doing and could remove something important.

Comment: @EsmeMo if the document is intended for electronic submission check first if biblatex is supported (almost all journals only accept bibtex and would not accept a biblatex version)

Comment: @Bernard - Recommending a change from using `natbib` (and BibTeX) to using `biblatex` is somewhat incomplete, as far as recommendations go. You ought to provide a suggestion for the citation style as well, I believe.

Comment: @Mico: It was a mere suggestion to take a look at the possibilities, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

It does change because this is simply what that particular style does in the BibTeX layer. You can see easily what happens if you look into the derived `.bbl`:

> ```
> \begin{thebibliography}{xx}
> \harvarditem{Krebs}{1980}{krebs1980optimal}
> Krebs, J.  \harvardyearleft 1980\harvardyearright , `Optimal foraging,
>   predation risk and territory defence', {\em Ardea} {\bf 68},~83--90.
> \end{thebibliography}
> ```

The '68' is inside a group in which the (obsolte) font command `\bf` is issued, which formats the groups content bold. You can try

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{krebs1980optimal,
    title={Optimal foraging, predation risk and territory defence},
    author={Krebs, JR},
    journal={Ardea},
    volume={68},
    pages={83--90},
    year={1980},
    publisher={BioOne}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{natbib}

\let\oldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand\thebibliography{\let\bf\relax\oldthebibliography}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: example_rendered]

It is worth noting that this will disable `\bf` in the *whole* bibliography.

Answer (score 2):

You can quite easily modify the `bst` file.

1. Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX system
2. Copy it in the same folder as your `.tex` document, with the name `agsm-nobf.bst`
3. Open the new file with any text editor
4. Find in it the only line containing the string `\bf`
5. Edit so that it becomes

   ```
   FUNCTION {embolden}
   { duplicate$ empty$
       { pop$ "" }
   %    { "{\bf " swap$ * "}" * }
       { "{" swap$ * "}" * }
     if$
   }
   ```

   (I left the original one, but commented out, for future memory)

Now your file can become

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{krebs1980optimal,
  title={Optimal foraging, predation risk and territory defence},
  author={Krebs, JR},
  journal={Ardea},
  volume={68},
  pages={83--90},
  year={1980},
  publisher={BioOne}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single,breaklines=true}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}


\title{PAPER TITLE}
\date{}

\begin{document}
TEXT HERE \nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{agsm-nobf}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

A few things to note. I removed `\sloppy` and you should do it as well. The `filecontents*` environment is just for convenience here, in order to make the example self-contained; you'll use your `bibliography.bib` file, but the call should be

```
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

***without*** `.bib`.

Compile, run BibTeX and compile again.

[image]

Comment: The only place where the `embolden` function is used in `agsm.bst` is inside the `format.vol.num.pages` function, on the line that reads `{ volume embolden field.or.null`. An alternative to the approach you provide would be to change the preceding line to `{ volume field.or.null`. That said, both approaches produce the exact same output. :-)

Comment: @Mico I went for a minimal patch; I thought about removing `embolden`, but my command of the bst language is limited.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I'm using the `natbib` package for the bibliography, and initially had the `plainnat` style but have since been told that I've got to use Harvard referencing only. So I tried changing the bibliography styles to ones I've found on online reference sheets - e.g. `agsm.bst`, ...

It is *not* necessary to change bibliography styles if all you need to do is change the style of the citation call-outs from numeric style to "harvard" style, which is also known as author-year style. While it is true that `agsm` is one of the style files provided by the `harvard` package, you do not have to switch to `agsm` (or one of the six other bibliography styles provided by the `harvard` package) in order to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs.

There are lots and lots of bibliography styles out there capable of generating authoryear-style citation call-outs. In fact, if you are otherwise satisfied with the formatting generated by the `plainnat` bibliography style, all you need to do is state the option `authoryear` while loading `natbib`. (By default, square brackets will be used; if you prefer round parentheses, state the option `round` as well.) Use `\citet` to generate "textual" citation call-outs and `\citep` to generate "parenthetic" citation call-outs.

Of course, if you prefer the formatting generated by the `agsm` style, by all means switch to `agsm` style. Just be aware that it is not *necessary* to do so if all you need to do is change the style of the citation call-outs.

---

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{krebs1980optimal,
  title={Optimal foraging, predation risk and territory defence},
  author ={Krebs, J. R.},
  journal={Ardea},
  volume={68},
  pages={83--90},
  year={1980},
  publisher={BioOne}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in}

\begin{document}
\citet{krebs1980optimal}; \citep{krebs1980optimal}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```